# Помогите реализовать section

Tags: html, css

Помогите решить проблему: не понимаю, как реализовать секцию на сайте, без Bootstrap.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И с чем же у вас проблемы возникли?

Comment: @Cheg, подозреваю, что с фонами за центрирующим контейнером

Comment: я вот не понимаю как так сделать чтобы 50% был один блок и у него был бордер, а второй с фоткой и поверх них еще контейнер и в контейнере блок с текстом.

Comment: @YuraKruhlyk а где на скриншоте у вас фотки?

Comment: серые это фотки просто в макете нет фоток, это как заглушка но там будут фотки

Comment: @YuraKruhlyk а фотки фоном или через img?

Comment: img  нужно вставить

Comment: я вот пробовал
http://kruhlyk.me/work/versak/
но теперь у меня контейнер 0 высоты и рамка скачет на другие секшены не очень хорошо вышло, может можно поправить?

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}

.section-1:before,
.section-1:after,
.section-2:before,
.section-2:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.section-1:before {    
    left: 0;
    border: 10px solid tomato;    
}
.section-1:after {      
    right: 0;
    background: url(http://static.trip101.com/paragraph_media/pictures/000/071/493/large/utahcover.jpg?1476069846) no-repeat right top;
    background-size: cover;
}

.section-2:before {    
    right: 0;
    border: 10px solid tomato;    
}
.section-2:after {      
    left: 0;
    background: url(http://static.trip101.com/paragraph_media/pictures/000/071/493/large/utahcover.jpg?1476069846) no-repeat right top;
    background-size: cover;
}

.container {
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
}
```

```html
<section class="section-1">
<div class="container">
    container
</div>
</section>
<section class="section-2">
<div class="container">
    container 
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: там еще у левого блока бордер должен быть а там где серое это будут фотки

Comment: а адаптив можно будет с этим сделать?

Comment: @Yura Kruhlyk да

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border: #fafafa solid 10px;
}

.img {
  background: #ccc;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.img img {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}

section.section-left .img {
  left: 50%;
  right: -10px;
}

section.section-right .img {
  right: 50%;
  left: -10px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.inner {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.section-left .inner {}

.section-right .inner {
  margin-left: 50%;
}

.section-left .inner {
  border-right: #fafafa solid 10px;
}

.section-right .inner {
  border-left: #fafafa solid 10px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-left">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/new_tn2s/misty-castle_tn2.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      Текст
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="section-right">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/new_tn2s/brasil-copacabana_tn2.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      Текст
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```